# The winning strategy in this game

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The problem in question is Problem 3 in [this question paper](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2015/zio2015/zio2015-question-paper.pdf). I just have no idea how to get the right answer without guessing. Is there a mathematically sound way to do this?

The answers are [here](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2015/zio2015/zio2015-solutions.pdf). 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is from an Informatics Olympiad, not a Mathematics Olympiad. Also, the rules state that no calculators or log tables are required. Therefore the goal must be to find an algorithm which can be carried out by hand.

The score produced by each position is calculated by a process which moves from left to right. In other words, the score produced by position $i$ does not depend on any decisions made about positions $i+1$ to $n$. Rather it depends on two things: do we select it, and what is the colour of the nearest selected position to its left. Just one colour: i.e. the amount of information we need to take from the left is constant, not dependent on $i$.

This is a classic setup for a dynamic programming algorithm. Define $f(i, j)$ to be the greatest possible score obtained selecting only positions from $1$ to $i$ where the rightmost selected position is $j \le i$, using the special value $j = -1$ to indicate that no positions are selected. Then we can evaluate $f$ recursively:

- $f(i, -1) = 0$
- $f(i, j) = f(i-1, j)$ when $j < i$
- $f(i, i) = \max_{-1 \le j < i} \left( f(i-1, j) + s(i, j) \right)$ where $s(i, j)$ is the number at position $i$ if positions $i$ and $j$ share a colour, and three times that otherwise. (Position $-1$ doesn't share a colour with any other position).